# team cooperation issue with CocoaPods

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, cocoapods

Our team use CocoaPods for package management, we just commit main project and Podfile to svn,    3rd party libs are not committed. Everyone does a "pod install" to get all the 3rd libs. My question is: What if we need to do some modifications to some 3rd libs, how to sync the change  to other members through svn ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a local pod (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-and-maintaining-a-pod) and [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/178)) containing the source tree of the library. To do this you import it to a directory in your VC and point the `Podfile` to the path where your modifications live. You will of course need to manually merge upstream  changes from the library.